# How to change the language of the Mathworks site?

Tags: matlab

I want to create an account in Mathworks website, but I found the website is in Korean language as in the picture!

Even, if I searched for any question in matlab, the pages of mathworks are open in Korean language!

So, How I can to change the language into English with Mathworks?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to scroll down the site and you will find the regional setting set up as a button with a globe in it. Click there and change the settings to a familiar one.

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple, goto end of webpage on webite and click region icon select Australia or India

Image to follow for process

[image: 1]